# Can I declare a span tag inside a div tag?

Tags: html

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="HomeScreen.html">Home</a> | 
    <span id="menu1">
        <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

The CSS for the ids "menu" and "menu1" is as follows :

```
#menu a:visited{
color:#0000FF;
}

#menu1 a:visited {
color: #48A89E;
}
```

The span Id is not able to over-ride the div id and I am getting blue color in output for both span and div.
Can't I write span inside div? Kindly explain.

Comment: make fiddle for your question.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/jsfiddle-an-online-playground-for-your-javascript-html-css/    
http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/14/what-is-jsfiddle-the-ultimate-guide-for-the-ultimate-lightweight-tool-q-249-250/

Comment: This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1n5oj3dg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have span tag inside div tag.

since span is an inline tag, by adding display : **block** or **inline-block** to span tag you can give it signifigance for its style to be visible.

```
 #menu1 a:visited {

    display: inline-block;
    color: #00ff00;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmahent/j2dfd8r0/6/

Comment: actually I had to do chaining of ids. Then I got the desired output.

Comment: oh ok, so instead of #menu1 you used `#menu #menu1 a:visited { }`